# Pl/SQL Рекурсия или итерация. Функция, которая вызывает сама себя

Tags: oracle, plsql

подскажите, как написать функцию, которая найдет последнее значение, подставляя в цикле предыдущее.
Есть объекты 1, 2, 3...10, у каждого объекта, кроме первого, есть свойство - это номер предыдущего объекта, так например у объекта 2 свойство = 1 и т.д..
Мне нужно, давая на вход номер первого (или любого другого) объекта вычислить последний.
У меня есть функция

```
create or replace function get_actual(l_loc in number) return number is
l_res number;
p_loc number;
begin
  begin
    select lp.id 
      into p_loc 
      from prop lp 
     where lp.prop_int = l_loc;
    l_res := p_loc;
    if p_loc is null then
      l_res := l_loc;
    end if;
   exception
     when others 
       then l_res := l_loc;
   end; 
   return l_res;
end;
```

Если на входе будет номер 1, то при помощи поиска она найдет номер 2, потому что в свойствах 2 есть номер 1.
Как написать так, чтобы она продолжила искать значение 3, у которого в свойствах значение 2, которое мы нашли в первой итерации и так до последнего где проставлено свойство.
Спасибо.

Comment: А функция-то тут зачем? рекурсивный CTE всё сделает без функций.

Comment: Планирую её использовать в процедурах

Comment: Ну так сунь запрос в функцию да бери "последнюю" запись из результата запроса. Рекурсивный запрос будет работать быстрее, чем итерации "вручную".

Comment: Сейчас буду пробовать, спасибо.